# Hibernate implementation of JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, rest, jpa

I'm wanting using JPA in ear project. Development project must be started ASAP so I have not a lot of time to research and investigate. Could you say please JPA API is restricted functionality of Hibernate or no. At this moment I'm using Hibernate directly. For example in future I'm planing to use hibernate-search and maybe hibernare-validate and -shard. Can I be sure that in future I will not have problem with using this. 
And one more example - can I use HAR archive and JPA together. 
Why JPA? For project will available RESTful service (jersey or resteassy implementation). And as I looked in much case using JPA for this. I'm a newbie in this so it's only my IMHO. May be i mistakes.

Thanks a lot.
Best regards 
Artem

Comment: This might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/530215/hibernate-vs-jpa-vs-jdo-pros-and-cons-of-each

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JPA is a subset of hibernate, but you're not limited to it. If you need a hibernate specific feature, you can generally use it at the cost of being tied to hibernate. For example, we've mixed in hibernate annotations with JPA ones, including the validater ones, without trouble.

Comment: Hi sblundy, your answer give confidence:) May be you also know about HAR. Can I use persistence and hibernate archive together?

Comment: @Tioma: I don't have experience with HAR, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

JPA in theory lets you change the persistance provider later.

Sticking to only JPA compatible configuration can cause more trouble that is solved by the dubious promise of seamlessly swapping providers however.