# Is Hibernate needed for Google App Engine?

Tags: database, hibernate, google-app-engine

I am new to java.  I thought hibernate is to deal with database.  And google app engine already has database api.  So does that mean we don't need hibernate for google app engine?  Or if still need, then why?

Comment: No. They have another ORM

Answer (score 1):

In case you are working with Relational database, maybe JDO is for you since JDO is both an object-relational mapping standard and a transparent object persistence standart. So, no , there is no need of Hibernate here

https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/appengine_orm
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jdo/overview

But consider, for a cloud platform, using of non relational (NoSQL) database, if it's possible for your case

Answer (score 1):

Hibernate is one of several [object-rational mapping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) (ORM) frameworks. It is an implementation of the Java Persistence API (JPA). Google App Engine uses DataNucleus, another ORM framework, and you can choose between Java Data Objects (JDO) and JPA. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/530215/hibernate-vs-jpa-vs-jdo-pros-and-cons-of-each) for more details about these frameworks.